# UWP ListView - DragOver not called anymore

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, listviewitem

I'm facing an issue that I can't solve. I have a ListView and I need to customize item style when the user drag an object over the list view item. Due to the complexity of my states, I don't want to keep the ListViewItemPresenter of the extended ListViewItem style. So when i remove that presenter and define my own style (basically a classic content presenter + overlay + underlay + VisualStateGroups to define animations), I don't recieve the DragOver and Drop event anymore on my list item objects. I don't understand why ? If i keep the default item container style it works fine... What did i miss?

Let me go a bit further with some code. Here is my List view that define **ItemTemplate** and **ItemContainerStyle** :

```
<ListView x:Name="notebookListView"  
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind NoteBookItems}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NotebookItemListViewTemplate}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource notebookItemContainerStyle}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="False" CanDragItems="True"
          DragItemsStarting="NotebookListView_DragItemsStarting"
          DragItemsCompleted="NotebookListView_DragItemsCompleted"
          ItemClick="NotebookItem_Click" />
```

Here is the item template that define the **DragOver** and **Drop** method:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="NotebookItemListViewTemplate" x:DataType="model:NotebookItem">
  <Grid x:Name="notebook" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Width="320"
        AllowDrop="True"
        DragOver="DragOverNotebookItem" 
        Drop="DropInNotebookItem">
   [...]
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And finaly my extended item container style:

```
<Style x:Key="notebookItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <!-- all default setter properties ... -->
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <!-- Here is my customization with VisualState to catch PointerOver and other events above my list items -->
        <Grid>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ColorUIBlackAlpha04}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ColorUIBlackAlpha12}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ColorUIBlackAlpha12}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlay" Duration="0" To="Transparent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <!-- and a Grid that contains the definition of the item content -->
          <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="underlay" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0" />
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              Background="Transparent"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="overlay" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

With that code, the **DragOver** event of my item is never triggered. But if i use the default item container style with the default ListViewItemPresenter it works fine. I don't understand why... Could anyone help me to understand what happens ?

**Here is the default list view item container style, with the ListViewItemPresenter instead of my custo:**

```
<Style x:Key="notebookItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}"/>
  <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
  <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
  <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="2"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <ListViewItemPresenter CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}" 
                               ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                               CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}" 
                               ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                               CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" 
                               DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}" 
                               DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                               DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}" 
                               DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" 
                               FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" 
                               FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" 
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                               Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" 
                               PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" 
                               PressedBackground="{StaticResource UIBlackAlpha12}" 
                               PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" 
                               PointerOverBackground="{StaticResource UIBlackAlpha04}" 
                               ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                               SelectedPressedBackground="Transparent" 
                               SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" 
                               SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}" 
                               SelectedPointerOverBackground="Transparent" 
                               SelectedBackground="Transparent" 
                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue, but I don't know the reason that caused this issue. I will continue to study this issue. Currently, there is a workaround for you. I found you want to modify the color of `underlay` `overlay` Rectangle. You could realize this in the code behind rather than in xaml with `Visualtreehelper`.

```
private void MYListview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    StackPanel test = MyFindListViewChildByName(MYListview.ContainerFromItem(MYListview.SelectedItem), "MyTest") as StackPanel;
    test.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}

public static DependencyObject MyFindListViewChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = MyFindListViewChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You could use `VisualTreeHelper` to get `underlay` `overlay` Rectangle instance then create animation for them. You could invoke those animation manually in ListViewItem event handler that match xaml `VisualStateGroup`.